# What's the equivalent of IntelliJ IDEA's Run/Debug Configurations "Before launch:" feature in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, command, run-configuration

IntelliJ IDEA in its Run/Debug Configurations dialog allows adding internal and external commands that are invoked before the actual program or test. Is there something similar in Eclipse? Is there maybe a plugin that would do the job?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an equivalent feature in Eclipse.  Certainly not with "vanilla" Eclipse.